# How to release control out of memory before application shuts down?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, finalizer

I have a very bad performance issue. I´m currently working on a multi-window application, but when I close one of the windows no memory is deallocated.

There are even controls I instantiate in code and after I used them I assigned null to their fields but nothing. The GC refuses to collect the control although there is no reference on it any more.

Googling that problem brought me to `Application.Exit` and `Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted` but they do not solve my problem, cause the application keeps on running.

I made a small sample to show you my problem:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <Window x:Class="FinalizerSampleProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinalizerSampleProject"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Get rid of the custom control!" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" x:Name="DummyButton" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace FinalizerSampleProject
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CustomControl control = new CustomControl();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(control);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (control != null)
        {
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(control);
            control = null;
            DummyButton.Content = "Show how many instances of CustomControl still exist.";
            GC.Collect();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(CustomControl.InstanceCounter.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

**CustomControl.xaml**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="FinalizerSampleProject.CustomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="LightGreen">
        <TextBlock Text="Hi, I'm a custom control!"/>
</UserControl>
```

**CustomControl.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace FinalizerSampleProject
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CustomControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public static int InstanceCounter = 0;
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InstanceCounter++;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ~CustomControl()
    {
        InstanceCounter--;
    }
}
}
```

If you try it, you will see that this counter every time appears to be "one". I have no idea how to get rid of that object instance.

Comment: You have to remember that first the `GC` won't be triggered immediately after you invoke `GC.Collect()`. You should see it more a "suggestion" to `GC` rather than a direct instruction. Secondly, the destructor (or finalize method) isn't executed on the first `GC` run. When `GC` spots an object with the finalize method it only adds it to the f-reachable collection, moves the object to a dormant state and on the second run runs the finalize method. That's why you see the `InstanceCounter` being set to 1.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski ok, but when does the GC invoke the finalize method? I can wait for minutes and it is not invoked.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This answer would only apply if the question was about the WinForms UserControl.**

---

Your custom controls are probably disposed and "freed" as they should. It's just that your finalizer code isn't invoked because when a UserControl is disposed it tells the garbage collector to NOT invoke its finalizer.

This is the standard `Dispose` implementation that suppress finalizers from being called:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

That code comes from `System.ComponentModel.Component`. And your `CustomControl` class derive from that via `UserControl`.

The line `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` is what prevents your counter from decrementing. No worries though, the instances are disposed (and collected by the GC).

Try this instead:

```
public static int InstanceCounter = 0;
private bool disposed;

public CustomControl()
{
    InstanceCounter++;
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && !this.disposed)
    {
        InstanceCounter--;
        this.disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it could be that somehow the `GC.SuppressFinalize` method is called, but `UserControl` does not implement `IDisposable`. So it is not called within `Dispose`

Comment: @christoph Yes, `UserControl` do implement `IDisposable` because it derive from `System.ComponentModel.Component` (which has the actual implementation).

Comment: Can it be that you mistake it with the WinForms UserControl?

Comment: @christoph Doph! Yes I am. Sorry!